Structure of elements of a finite group not contained in any conjugate of a proper subgroup
Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a proper subgroup of $G$. It is elementary to prove that the union of all conjugates of $H$ under $G$,
$$U:=\bigcup_{\sigma\in G}\sigma^{-1}H\sigma,$$
is properly contained in $G$. In fact, it is also straightforward to prove that $\#G\setminus U\geq\#H$.
I have heard that, using the classification of finite simple groups, one can prove that $G\setminus U$ always contains an element of prime-power order.
Does anyone have a reference for this fact? I guess it probably involves a case analysis using the classification?

Consider the action of $G$ on the set of right cosets of $H$ in $G$. An element $g$ that does not lie in $U$ is a fixed-point-free element in this action, also known as a derangement. The existence of derangements of prime power order is a result of Fein, Kantor and Schacher: https://zbmath.org/0457.13004

Peter Cameron mentions the FKS result in these slides -- https://cameroncounts.github.io/web/talks/16YRM/pjc_yrm1.pdf -- where he does indeed assert that it involves a case analysis.

As Nick Gill mentioned in a comment, the reference for this result is
B. Fein, W.M. Kantor and M. Schacher, Relative Brauer groups II, J. Reine Angew. Math. 328 (1981), 39–57.
